# rename all files with the same name in all subdirectories

Tags: rename

I have a directory with 45 sub directories in it, I want to change all the .html file in the sub dirs that have specific name to another name but keep the .html extension. 
How to I do that in terminal please in opensuse?

maybe with 'rename" or with 'find' command ?

thanks

Comment: Apart from not being a programming question, you did not specify the operating system you are using. Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Which OS are you trying to achieve this in?

Comment: `terminal` leads to some *X probably...

Comment: What language are you hoping to code in to do this task?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the OS, opensuse,  and I want to do that with either "rename" or "for f in" in shell.